# Creating a yaml file with aliases through PyYAML

Tags: python, yaml, alias, pyyaml, cross-reference

I need to create a yaml file with the following format:

```
imager: &imager
  type: "detector"
  half_angle: 75 degrees
  max_distance: 23000 meters
ownship: &ownship
  origin: [11,11,5]
  type: "uav"

vehicles:
  - <<: *ownship
  name: "uav1"
  origin: [35.69257148103399 degrees, -117.689417544709 degrees, 5500]
  sensors:
    - <<: *imager
      name: "imager1"
```

I have all the specific data stored in Python classes, so I figured I'd use PyYAML to make things easy.  However, when I went to read the documentation, I saw no mention of how to handle aliases with PyYAML.  Does this functionality exist, or should I just go ahead and make my own yaml writer?

Comment: I updated my answer, as my ruamel.yaml library (which has a superset of PyYAML functionality) now has the capability to round-trip this file without loss of merge and anchor/reference information. Creating from scratch is more difficult, but you should be able to easily start with a template YAML file, read that in and save it.

Comment: I posted this answer on a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/36295979/150050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the file you specify is not correct YAML. It will not read in because here:

```
- <<: *ownship
name: "uav1"
```

you juxtapose a sequential element and a mapping element and that is not allowed. If you remove the `-` from the first line you get a correct YAML file:

```
imager: &imager
  type: "detector"
  half_angle: 75 degrees
  max_distance: 23000 meters
ownship: &ownship
  origin: [11,11,5]
  type: "uav"

vehicles:
  - <<: *ownship
  name: "uav1"
  origin: [35.69257148103399 degrees, -117.689417544709 degrees, 5500]
  sensors:
    - <<: *imager
      name: "imager1"
```

that you **cannot** generate with PyYAML.

PyYAML does support anchors and references for reading and writing. And it does support the [merge key operator](http://yaml.org/type/merge.html) `<<` for reading. But it does not support writing of the merge operator.

That would require comparing different dictionaries, determining if any dict is a complete subset (all keys and values of the one being in the other) of another dict and then making an anchor on the subset and adding the merge operator on writing the other dict (and not writing the keys in the subset).
There is no such code in PyYAML to do so, as it is much more complicated than using anchors and references on shared complex objects (`dict`, `list` etc) which PyYAML does support.

My [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), which has a superset of PyYAML functionality, does support round-tripping of such data starting with version 0.10. It does some "normalisation" on the first round-trip:

```
imager: &imager
  type: detector
  half_angle: 75 degrees
  max_distance: 23000 meters
ownship: &ownship
  origin: [11, 11, 5]
  type: uav
vehicles:
  <<: *ownship
  name: uav1
  origin: [35.69257148103399 degrees, -117.689417544709 degrees, 5500]
  sensors:
  - <<: *imager
    name: imager1
```

It is easy to just read in that YAML and manipulate the resulting data-structure and then write it out. Assignment of keys is done on the dictionary you reference, retrieval of a value is transparently done from the first merged dictionary if not available in the referenced dictionary.

Creating such a structure from scratch and then dumping it is more difficult, as there are no supporting routines to create merges by comparing keys/values between dictionaries (yet).

Comment: Does ruamel.yaml support custom loaders and custom presenters as PyYAML does? At the moment I need to be able to preserve ordering of my elements (hence I need a custom OrderedDict loader), consistent quoted presentation, as well as preserving merge, anchor, and reference operators.

Comment: @skeletalbassman Yes it has the same setup for loaders/presenters. The sources don't differ that much. I am not sure though what your exact interpretation of "consistent quoted presentation" is ( I have seen people expect key scalars to be unquoted and value scalars to be quoted within the same mapping). Give it a try and post a question on [so] if things don't immediately work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

It looks as if PyYAML does the right thing if your python data structure contains multiple references to the same object.  Consider, for example, this:

```
>>> a = {'name': 'bob', 'office': '100'}
>>> b = {'president': a, 'vice-president': a}
>>> b
{'president': {'name': 'bob', 'office': '100'}, 'vice-president': {'name': 'bob', 'office': '100'}}
>>> import yaml
>>> print yaml.dump(b)
president: &id001 {name: bob, office: '100'}
vice-president: *id001
```

PyYAML has recognized that the values for both the 'president' and 'vice-president' keys are references to the same object, and has created an alias and used it appropriately.

Comment: The shared objects is not the problem, it is the merge key (`<<`) that is not supported at all on writing.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed exactly what you wanted; you asked explicitly about aliases.